# Using 'convertXLStoCSV' results in ''Failed to load as a DOM Document'

Tags: php, excel, csv

I've used `convertXLStoCSV` extensively on many files and it usually works well to convert an Excel file to a .csv.

For some reason on one particular file I keep on getting `Failed to load as a DOM Document` and it references `/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php:435`.

Now, if I manually open the file, save it to my local machine and try again it works fine. I don't have control over the file but clearly there is something unique or corrupt about it.

Can anyone suggest a programmatic option that can open and re-save the file locally?

My code is simply:

```
if(file_exists('data/file.xls')) {
        convertXLStoCSV('data/file.xls', 'data/file.csv');
}
```

Comment: Open that file in a text editor and see if it really is an xls file (a binary, which makes it largely unreadable by sane human beings) or a block of HTML markup (which should be easily recognisable by any normal human being involved in web development)

Comment: In notepad it shows mostly gibberish with the file contents interspersed throughout. Definitely not HTML.

Comment: Then very odd that it should be identified as HTML by PHPExcel.... but without knowing what it actually is makes it almost impossible to suggest anything

Comment: True. That's why I was wondering if there is some way to open and then re-save as xls. That way I can avoid trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Well if it's not possible to identify what type of file it really is, then it's pretty difficult to parse it into something that can be saved as an xls.... PHPExcel doesn't work by magic, it has a set of rules to try and identify a file format, and once it's identified the format it can try to parse it according to the structure that is defined for that format.... when those rules don't work, or if the file doesn't follow the defined structure, then it can't do much. But PHPExcel can't simply work out new formatting rules for files that don't comply

Comment: is there some kind of general open file and save file options without using PHPExcel that might work? I trued `copy` but that didn't work.

Comment: You go find this black magic box..... I'm not aware of any script that can take an arbitrary file that doesn't comply with any recognised format and massage it into an xls file...... if I was, I'd be selling it and making a fortune

Comment: Thanks! Giving up on this......